# Python parse POST in Lambda

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a simple HTTP POST handler in Python (running on Lambda) dealing with data sent from a simple html form (i.e. application/x-www-form-urlencoded). I am not very familiar with Python. My code appears to be parsing the data but the output is not a form which Python can process?

I was using the instructions provided by AWS at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html#lambda-examples-access-request-body-examples-read

Using both bash PHP, if I base64 encode `email=user%40example.com&message=hello+world`, I get:

```
ZW1haWw9dXNlciU0MGV4YW1wbGUuY29tJm1lc3NhZ2U9aGVsbG8rd29ybGQ=
```

However when I decode this in Python, I get a "binary" string. While I can still run parse_qs().items against this, the returned key/value pairs are binary strings and subsequent operations fail.

Hopefully, this code illustrates what I am trying to achieve:

```
import base64
from urllib.parse import parse_qs


# s = "email=user%40example.com&message=hello+world"
s = "ZW1haWw9dXNlciU0MGV4YW1wbGUuY29tJm1lc3NhZ2U9aGVsbG8rd29ybGQ="
s =  base64.b64decode(s)
postVars = {k: v[0] for k, v in parse_qs(s).items()}
if ("email" in postVars) and ("message" in postVars) and (0<len(postVars['message'])):
        body = body + "Email: " + postVars['email'] + "\n"
        body = body + div + bodyCleanUp(postVars['message']) + "\n"
else:
        body="Error: message content missing or blank\n"

print (postVars['email'])
print (postVars['message']
```

The `if` expression evaluates as false. Eexcution fails at the first print statement.

How can I get the data in a form that Python does not choke on?

Comment: If you convert from binary string to a general string, does that resolve the issue?

Comment: Probably - but how exactly do I do that?

Comment: Use the `.decode(...)` method for binary strings. `b'a string'.decode('utf-8')` will convert a binary string to UTF-8 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, `base64.b64decode(s)` is producing a binary string. Decode into UTF-8 and you should be working with standard Python strings.

```
s = base64.b64decode(s).decode('utf-8')
```

Then, the rest of the code should work how you expect.

Here is a minimal reproducible example. Source:

```py
import base64
from urllib.parse import parse_qs

s = "ZW1haWw9dXNlciU0MGV4YW1wbGUuY29tJm1lc3NhZ2U9aGVsbG8rd29ybGQ="
s =  base64.b64decode(s).decode("utf-8")
postVars = {k: v[0] for k, v in parse_qs(s).items()}
print(postVars)
```

Output:

```
{'email': 'user@example.com', 'message': 'hello world'}
```